# I cant break down the problem with identifier "num" is undefined and 'num': undeclared identifier

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to understand if the input argument is a number or not WITHOUT using isadigit() function but by using a compounded logical expression. All was going well untill i am met with this error that i cant break down or resolve. any ideas/ solution?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

void checkValid1(string num);

for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
    int Firtsnumber = atoi(argv[1]);

    // if c is not digit
    if (Firtsnumber < '0' || Firtsnumber>'9') {
        cout << "CheckValid1 : Invalid..!!\n";
        return 0;
    }


}

cout << "CheckValid1 : Valid expression\n";
}
```

Comment: What error is it?

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish by declaring some function called `checkValid1` ***inside*** main? The whole thing looks like multiple attempts to fix compilation errors by making random syntax changes, but without understanding the underlying compilation errors, and now getting to this end result. VTC as a typo.

Comment: @davidG is in the question. but here: "identifier "num" is undefined" and " num': undeclared identifier"

Comment: Your code seems a bit jumbled. You have `num` declared as an argument for `checkValid1`. You have a function`checkValid1` declared inside of the function `main` but it's not defined anywhere. The body of `main` is referencing `num` which is not defined within `main`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik oh so it should be outside main right?

Comment: Well, the whole function should be, not just its declaration.

Comment: @lurker in fact it's valid to declare function inside function.

Comment: @appleapple yep my bad. I corrected my comment. I should indicate it's *declared* but not *defined* anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to create a function called checkValid1, thats not how you do it. Plus the logic is all wrong too.

you need

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool checkValid1(string num){
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
       char c = num[i];
       // if c is not digit
       if (c < '0' || c>'9') {
          cout << "CheckValid1 : Invalid..!!\n";
          return false;
       }
  }
  cout << "CheckValid1 : Valid expression\n";
  return true;
}

int main(){
    cout << checkValid1("12a");
}
```

Comment: You may want to make a case for using [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews OP said they did not want to use it